# Lambda expression cannot hold parameter

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
[SerializeField] List<Button> Buttons;
void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.Count; i++)
    {
        Buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => DoThing(i));// can't hold i variable
        //when click the each button result is always 3
        // i want 0,1,2
        print(i); // 0,1,2
    }
}
public void DoThing(int value)
{
    print(value);
}
```

I want to use i as parameter of a button click event action but each button always prints 3. Instead of using i Buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => DoThing(2)) is working fine. how use i as parameter

Comment: Captured variables have their lifetime extended by moving them to a generated class. Be careful how you capture them. https://sharplab.io/#v2:CYLg1APgAgTAjAWAFBQMwAJboMLoN7LpGYZQAs6AygPYC2ApgC4AWAlgHYDmAFFAKwAeDowB86AMYBKPAF9CxNJgoBZbpPzzixAGbUATtwBuAQz3pWAXgAMAblYC4t1mDCTNWjzQYsOPNegsxVkkbdy1dAxMzSycHJxdpMI8iKPQAKwtWUKRk5K8mNi5uf0D0kKSiORziKpkgA==

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code, `DoThing` will capture the variable `i` (and not its value) and will only get the value of `i` when you invoke onClick.

Copy the value of a changing variable to the scope where the closure is defined

```
[SerializeField] List<Button> Buttons;

void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.Count; i++)
    {
        var iLocal = i;
        Buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(() => DoThing(iLocal));
    }
}

public void DoThing(int value)
{
    print(value);
}
```

This fix makes sure that when you get the context where the action was created, `iLocal` will hold the value corresponding to the index of the button in the list.

Answer (score 0):

Despite the Answer, i discourage you to use lambda as all to link an event. Why? Because you cannot unsubscribe an anonymous function, you should really link in this way.

https://learn.microsoft.com/it-it/dotnet/standard/delegates-lambdas

```cs
[SerializeField] List<Button> Buttons;

void Start()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.Count; i++)
    {
        Buttons[i].onClick.AddListener(DoThing);
    }
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < Buttons.Count; i++)
    {
        Buttons[i].onClick.RemoveListener(DoThing);
    }
}

public void DoThing(int value)
{
    print(value);
}
```